# How do I view parents in the Current Iteration backlog

Tags: azure-devops

How do I view parents in the Current Iteration backlog?

[image]

In the **Stories** backlog you have a show button for parents

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not supported on iteration backlog.

However you can make a **Tree of work items** query to view parent/child in the specific iteration:

[image]

Comment: @ton.yeung Have you resolved the issue? Is that helpful? any update?

Answer (score 0):

you can't. it's only supported on the backlog level. Best you can do is make your own query